# How to set background of matplotlib with two rearranged axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have matplotlib widget (mpl) on my form (ui) from Qt designer. Then I plot some data with double axes:

```
ui.mpl.axes.plot(x, y1))
ax2 = ui.mpl.axes.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, y2)
```

[image]

Now I want my left-axis plot to lie upon right-axis one, so I change z order of axes:

```
ui.mpl.axes.set_zorder(ui.mpl.axes.get_zorder()+1)
```

After changing z-order my 2nd plot disappears, so I have to add:

```
ui.mpl.axes.patch.set_visible(False)
```

And I get this:

[image]

The question is how to return white background? Or maybe there's other way for changing the order of the axes?

this doesn't help:

```
ax2.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
```

Comment: Not sure about the relative zorder shift approach since it assumes that the two zorders are different by only one and when you set them equal they'll swap.  What happens if you read them both and do the swap.  Easier, though, 1) to just set the zorders to what you want using the `zorder` keyword in the plotting commend; 2) set them directly to `1` and `2`, after the plot.

Comment: thx, now code looks a bit clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes! it appeared the canvas of 2nd axis just wasn't visible by default. This solves it:

```
ax2.patch.set_visible(True)
```